# Unable to extract Auth code during authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, oauth

I have the following code which redirects the user to the auth url in which once authorization is given, a callback URL is returned containing the auth code. (There is no popup, authorization is done on the same window)

```
  authStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = {
      client_id: 'some-id',
      scopes: ["user:email", "notifications"]
    };
    var loginUrl = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?';
    var authUrl = loginUrl + 'client_id=' + options.client_id + '&scope=' + options.scopes;

    window.open(authUrl, "_parent");

    var authCode = this.getAuthCode(window.location.href);
    console.log(authCode);

  getAuthCode(url){
    var error = url.match(/[&\?]error=([^&]+)/);
    if (error) {
      throw 'Error getting authorization code: ' + error[1];
    }
    return url.match(/[&\?]code=([\w\/\-]+)/)[1];
  },
```

Running this, I am able to successfully get the callback URL in the window but unable to retrieve the auth code. What I think is that the getAuthCode function is called immediately after the window.open statement and since the window has not loaded completely yet there is nothing to retrieve. What should be done to avoid this. I am using ReactJS and node in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you cannot access the url of another browser window if it's not from the same origin. You would get the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://yourdomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at yourcode.js(xx:xx)

To understand why this would be a problem, imagine that you click on a link in a malicious website and then that website would be able to manipulate the newly opened window.

Comment: So what are the changes which I should do in order to avoid this ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @AronKarmer github redirects the user to the same page by default, so when window loads you need to add a check for `code` parameter. If it exists, you can authenticate the user.